# How to use Hashicorp Vault with NodeJS application?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have Node JS app inside pods, which needs to read vault secrets.
So far I found 2 methods for doing that

1. Using init container to mount secrets as .txt files and read/parse them in my app
2. Using node-vault connect to vault server directly and read secrets, which requires initial token

For (1) I found [this](https://blog.aquasec.com/managing-kubernetes-secrets) article, where the author is considering it as not secure and complex.

> Secrets mounted as volumes are unwieldy—secrets can be stored as
> environment variables or mounted as a volume. The former technique is
> widely agreed to be less secure. If you opt for volumes, things
> quickly get complex when you have a large number of keys. Kubernetes
> creates one file per key, and you need to read all these files from
> within the application. There are workarounds, but they can be equally
> complex.

For the (2) I am not sure how to automatically unseal and obtain initial tokens without using Amazon secrets or other services. Of course I can't hard code initial token or `roll_id/secret_id`. What is the typical way of obtaining and passing initial token to the pods?

Comment: Same question thread at vendor's site: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-use-hashicorp-vault-with-nodejs-application/21468/6 @pablo please share with us if you know more.

Answer (score 1):

As the Linux philosophy says:

> Make each program do one thing well

So it's worth it to use the vault agent, cause it's doing well what it would be done.

You can find an awesome example [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector)